# Keyboard layout in Terminal of Red Hat Linux changes automatically

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-layout, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an unique problem in Terminal of Red Hat Linux WS 6.6. After some of period of period (Don't know exactly when..) keyboard layout (and not language) changes from German to English ONLY in Terminal. In other programs (e.g. nedit or Openoffice etc..) it remains always German. I am not sure, how and when this is taking place. Is any of my script changing any environment variable or any other program.

What would you suggest, what can be the best way to figure it out?

I thought of following :

If I could write any shell script which at some time interval, say at every hour, would write time, environment variable LANG and all the processes ran in that hour on the whole system. So this would help me to figure out at what time LANG is changed and which processes caused it. What is your opinion about it?

If you think this would help, how can I write a shell script which would be continuously running in background and write above-stated variables.

Help of any sorts would be appreciated. This problem is literally bugging me now....

Thanks in advance.

Gunesh

Comment: First check: Do you have a keyboard shortcut that makes the keyboard switch from German to English or vice versa *(a note valid for Ubuntu: Super Space set to 'Switch to next source' under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing)*

Comment: I've moved the text above to an Answer as it seems to be "it", please mark as accepted (click the tick, to make it be green). :-)

Answer (score 0):

First check: Do you have a keyboard shortcut that makes the keyboard switch from German to English or vice versa

*A note valid for Ubuntu: by default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is set to 'Switch to next source' under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There was keyboard pattern change shortcut set as Shift+Caps Lock. I now have switched it off so it should not change layout anymore anymore whenever I mistakeny press these two keys together.

In Red Hat 6 under System --> Preferences --> Keyboard. This will pop up new window for Keyboard preferences. In this window, in layout tab, Layout Options --> Switching to another layout. Here, shortcut can be set. As per admin, this is default. 

This is system-wide setting. I will check it for a bit of time and if the problem goes away, THIS IS THE ANSWER.
Thanks alot.