# Windows 8.1 input language keeps changing randomly

Tags: windows-8.1, input-languages

I'm using windows 8.1 & working with 2 languages - English & Hebrew.
English is used as the main language.

My problems is that when I go between apps the input language keeps changing, it doesn't keep the last state of language so a lot of times I find out that I'm writing in the wrong language.

Example - I'm typing an address on Chrome in English, then going to Windows + R & typing a network path, then realizing that I wrote it in Hebrew & not in English.

On language preferences - English is on the top.
On advanced settings - Override Display - English is chosen.
On advanced settings - Override default input - English is chosen.
Formats - English (United states)
Location - United states

I've read a lot of threads here & on other forums & didn't find an answer.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you pressing `Shift+Alt` perhaps? It selects the next input language without an on-screen prompt.

Answer (score 1):

**The currently assigned shortcut key(s) for switching language might be something you do not expect.**

In the same manner as described [here for Redhat and Ubuntu Linux](https://superuser.com/q/964031/346288), there are keyboard shortcuts set up in Windows (still per default?) for **swithching** between English and an installation language dependent setting for the Keyboard.
Setting: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if I don't remember wrong.

Please check 'Control Panel' > 'Keyboard'.
I believe it is also reachable via 'Region & Language settings'

Comment: I'm not using the keyboard for changing language.
I'm typing, minimizing the screen, pressing win key + r to enter a path or just opening another application & the input language changes.
It can be from English to Hebrew or the other way.

Comment: Updated the info above.

Comment: I don't use any shortcut keys, just switching between application with the mouse. os language is english & I added a hebrew keyboard as well.